# Responsive menu link not opening

Tags: css

I'm hoping someone can help me with issue. I currently have a responsive menu in which the links don't load. When I hover on the link, I can see the link appear at the bottom of Chrome, but it doesn't do anything.

The menu is also part of a sticky header - when I scroll down, it works as the sticky menu but not when the menu itself is at the top.

I've tested it in other browsers with not much luck either.

Does anyone have any ideas what's going on?

Thanks!

Comment: Please add your code to the question so that we can actually help you solve your problem. How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Code snippet would be useful to have

Comment: In one of the many unecessary js files, there is this:
$('#topnav nav a,#topnav h1 a,#btmnav nav a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // stop all hash(#) anchor links from loading
  });

Comment: Thank you so much! That seems to have solved it :)